# if else php not displaying the message

Tags: php

test.php

```
<?php


echo '<form method="post" action="test2.php">

Age: <input type="text" name="age">

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">

</form>'



?>
```

test2.php

```
<?php


$age = $_POST["age"];

if ($age == null) {
    echo "Please enter your age.";
} else if ($age >= 18) {
    echo "You're at a legal age.";
} else if ($age < 18) {
    echo "You're a minor.";
}else {
    echo "Error";
}


?>
```

Why is that when I type letter in my input, it displays "You're a minor." instead of the message "Error"? What's the problem with my code?

Comment: use `$age = (int)$_POST["age"];`

Comment: PHP is kind of tricky about variables types. Don't trust them. In your example, you can see that PHP can compare a string with an int. But instead you can ask if is_int()

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty That is not his/h question.

Comment: @user3702825 That's why you sanitize the requests.

Comment: of course its an error, because its a string

Comment: use `exit` statment after every  `echo` statment

Answer (score 1):

When PHP tries to compare a string to a number, a string that cannot be converted to a number will have a numeric value of `0`.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

A simple solution would be to fail the age on the first condition if it isn't numeric, like so:

```
if ($age == null || !is_numeric($age)) {
    echo "Please enter your age.";
} else if ($age >= 18) {
    echo "You're at a legal age.";
} else if ($age < 18) {
    echo "You're a minor.";
}else {
    echo "Error";
}
```

Alternatively to `is_numeric()` you could also use `is_int()` to only allow whole numbers.

---

If I were you I'd let people enter their birthdate, which can just be dropped into the `DateTime` class and be handled much easier from there.

Comment: With what value of `$age` would "Error" be echoed?

Comment: @Antti29 I don't think it ever would. But maybe I'm overlooking something.

Comment: That was kind of my point. To make the code work as the OP intended, it would probably be wiser to include the `is_numeric()` check in the middle two `if`s. (That is not to say it's the best way to do it; just what the OP asked.)

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves
>   numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the
>   comparison performed numerically.

If the input is a string, it gets converted to a number:

```
var_dump((int) 'A'); // Result: 0
```

And `0` is less than `18`, that's why `You're a minor.` is displayed. You need to validate the input:

```
if(!is_numeric($_POST["age"])) {
  // Raise error.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $age = $_POST["age"];

   if(is_int($age)) 
   {
      if ($age >= 18) 
      {
         echo "You're at a legal age.";
      } 
      if ($age < 18) 
      {
         echo "You're a minor.";
      } 
   }
   else 
   {
       echo "Please enter an integer."; 
   }
```

You didn't check the type of the variable you get from the user! Be carefull about that, as he could just send non-wanted stuff, which is why you have to check his input.
keep in mind this check is still far from perfect, but it should do the job you're waiting it to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

When you send empty POST data, you have $_POST["age"] = '', not 'null'.
So your should have smth like

```
if ($age == ''){...
```

or 
    if ($age) {...

Comment: or `if (empty($age))` it looks for everything - `undefined`, `null`, `length == 0`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$age = $_POST["age"];

if(is_numeric($age)) {

 if ($age >= 18) {
     echo "You're at a legal age.";
 } else if ($age < 18) {
    echo "You're a minor.";
 }else {
    echo "Error";
 }
}else {

   echo "Error";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST[""])) {
    $age = $_POST["age"];

    if ($age == '') {
        echo "Please enter your age.";
    } else if ($age >= 18) {
        echo "You're at a legal age.";
    } else if ($age < 18) {
        echo "You're a minor.";
    } else {
        echo "Error";
    }
} else {
    echo "Data not Posting";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work for you

```
<?php
$age = $_POST["age"];

if(is_numeric($age)) 
{
 if ($age >= 18) 
 {
     echo "You're at a legal age.";
 } 
 else 
 {
    echo "You're a minor.";
 }
}
else {

   echo "Error";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check it with

```
$age = isset($_POST["age"]) ? $_POST['age'] : null;
$age = is_numeric($age) ? $age : null;
```

Comment: -1 The OP is not asking for a solution but WHY: `Why is that when I type letter in my input, it displays "You're a minor." instead of the message "Error"?`

Answer (score -3):

Because age are integer, force it to Integer

```
<?php

$age = intval($_POST["age"]);
// OR $age = (int) $_POST["age"];

if ($age == null) {
    echo "Please enter your age.";
} else if ($age >= 18) {
    echo "You're at a legal age.";
} else if ($age < 18) {
    echo "You're a minor.";
}else {
    echo "Error";
}


?>
```

Comment: -1 The OP is not asking for a solution but WHY: `Why is that when I type letter in my input, it displays "You're a minor." instead of the message "Error"?`

Comment: This would cause people who enter crap to be minors.

Comment: This won't display **Error** when `a` is entered.